# transform dataframe without lose data

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with many number of rows and columns like

```
    A       B       C       D
x           -2      3       
y   1               -4      2
z           1   
w   3       4       -2     -2
```

and i want to transform it to

```
x   A   0
x   B   -2
x   C   0
x   D   3
y   A   1
y   B   0
y   C   -4
y   D   2
z   A   0
z   B   0
z   C   1
z   D   0
w   A   3
w   B   4
w   C   -2
w   D   -2
```

what is the name for this transform?
can anyone help me how can make this transform ?
Thank you!!!

i try stack() but i dont take what i need...
can you help me ?

[the excel is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m6CKvmX8Rr-TC0Loj9eLhXsFmMlrTzhY/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=110868722487953011654&rtpof=true&sd=true)

the code i use is here:

```
catalogue = 'stack.xlsx'  # εδώ δηλώνω το όνομα και τύπο αρχείου που περιέχει όλα


import os

# to get the current working directory
directory = os.getcwd()
print('το path από αυτό τον φάκελο είναι:', directory)
###########################################################################################

import pandas as pd

catalogue_df  = pd.read_excel(catalogue, sheet_name= 'Sheet1')
print(len(catalogue_df))
print(catalogue_df)
print(type(catalogue_df))

print(30*"#")

catalogue_df = catalogue_df.fillna(0)
print(len(catalogue_df))
print(catalogue_df)
print(type(catalogue_df))

print(30*"#")

trans_df = catalogue_df.stack()
print(trans_df)
print(type(trans_df))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('from_stack.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
trans_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

and the result is:

```
/home/dim/PycharmProjects/20230114_project_ekka/venv/bin/python /home/dim/PycharmProjects/20230114_project_ekka/2023_ΜΕΤΑΘΕΣΕΙΣ/stackoverflow/stack.py 
το path από αυτό τον φάκελο είναι: /home/dim/PycharmProjects/20230114_project_ekka/2023_ΜΕΤΑΘΕΣΕΙΣ/stackoverflow
4
  level    A    B    C    D
0     x  NaN -2.0  3.0  NaN
1     y  1.0  NaN -4.0  2.0
2     z  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3     w  3.0  4.0 -2.0 -2.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
##############################
4
  level    A    B    C    D
0     x  0.0 -2.0  3.0  0.0
1     y  1.0  0.0 -4.0  2.0
2     z  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3     w  3.0  4.0 -2.0 -2.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
##############################
0  level      x
   A        0.0
   B       -2.0
   C        3.0
   D        0.0
1  level      y
   A        1.0
   B        0.0
   C       -4.0
   D        2.0
2  level      z
   A        0.0
   B        1.0
   C        0.0
   D        0.0
3  level      w
   A        3.0
   B        4.0
   C       -2.0
   D       -2.0
dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
/home/dim/PycharmProjects/20230114_project_ekka/2023_ΜΕΤΑΘΕΣΕΙΣ/stackoverflow/stack.py:35: FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version
  writer.save()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I try to my dataframe:
[this is xlsx file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17oyVNPTCucOBDMPtPC_BxQ46rwDxMJqI/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=110868722487953011654&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[and this is csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14lPhwjlGsIhxtlAO9PD_tLcTx9UxD8w8/view?usp=share_link)

but give me this error about column name but i dont see the wrong-error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dim/PycharmProjects/20230114_project_ekka/2023_ΜΕΤΑΘΕΣΕΙΣ/ΚΕΝΑ_ΜΕΤΑΘΕΣΕΙΣ_ΚΑΤΣΩΝΟΠΟΥΛΟΣ/stack/stack_csv.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = df.set_index('ΠΕΡΙΟΧΗ').fillna(0).stack().to_frame().reset_index()
  File "/home/dim/PycharmProjects/20230114_project_ekka/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dim/PycharmProjects/20230114_project_ekka/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6009, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['ΠΕΡΙΟΧΗ'] are in the columns"
```

can help me what is the error ?

Comment: use `df.stack()`

Comment: please see my edit update for result from stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've loaded your excel file as csv into a dataframe, the main operations are `stack`ing and reindexing that allow to obtain the expected output:

```
df = pd.read_csv('stack-test.csv')
df = df.set_index('level').fillna(0).stack().to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'value']
print(df)
```

---

```
   col1 col2  value
0     x    A    0.0
1     x    B   -2.0
2     x    C    3.0
3     x    D    0.0
4     y    A    1.0
5     y    B    0.0
6     y    C   -4.0
7     y    D    2.0
8     z    A    0.0
9     z    B    1.0
10    z    C    0.0
11    z    D    0.0
12    w    A    3.0
13    w    B    4.0
14    w    C   -2.0
15    w    D   -2.0
```

Comment: please see above the update ...i dont find where is the wrong ...
I take copy -paste the name but dont work

Comment: @dimzev. I got no errors when running `df = df.set_index('ΠΕΡΙΟΧΗ').fillna(0).stack().to_frame().reset_index()` on your updated file (saved as csv)

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter above said using df.stack() is the best solution. If you can supply some of your code so we can find the best way to solve your issue.

Here is a good article on df.stack(): https://towardsdatascience.com/reshaping-a-dataframe-with-pandas-stack-and-unstack-925dc9ce1289

Here is the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#

Comment: please see my edit update for result from stack